# Preventing initial focus

Tags: wpf, focus

I have a button that, when it has focus, has a special style.

I have a form with only a series of these fancy buttons; when it loads, the first button in the series is displaying the special style to indicate it has focus. It's functionally fine, but visually annoying.

I have resolved this with:

```
<TextBox width="1" Height="1" />
```

But this feels like a kludge.

Is there a better way to prevent anything from having the initial focus?

Comment: Usually it's the other way around since nothing is focused by default (at least not for me, I have to press tab to move the focus). Try this on the parent container `FocusManager.FocusedElement="{x:Null}"`

Comment: could you please add  the xaml code you are using in the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, focus should be on window and not on button. Are you  unknowingly, setting focus on button either using focus method or tab index?